# How to programatically set the home page for chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, c++

How to programatically set the home page for chrome and firefox? I have native client ( c plus plus  based ) running on the machine. Through that I would like to set home page of all the installed browsers to the URL which I want.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of uncomplimentary names for software that hijacks people's browser settings; perhaps your case is legitimate (although the only legitimate case I can think of is a managed installation of some kind, and for that you should be using the managed prefs systems that most browsers provide), but the effect will look the same as what malicious software does.

You should assume that if you find a way to do this, you will be getting into an arms race with browser vendors.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend doing this but if it's a legitimate need then see https://superuser.com/questions/287313/which-registry-keys-need-to-be-edited-to-change-the-default-browser

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question: how to change the default browser, where this is about how to change the default startup page for a browser (default or otherwise).